# Accessing autoconf defined symbols in python

Tags: python, c, autotools, autoconf

I'm working on a project that is written in both C++ and python. I have the following line in my configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT(MILHOUSE, 0.3.6)
```

which means that in the config.h generated by running configure, i have the following define line:

```
/* Define to the version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3.6"
```

I just wanted to know if there was an existing module for parsing configure symbols like this or at least a standard way of accessing these defines in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AC_INIT` not only defines preprocessor symbols, it also defines output variables. When you list a file, let's call it `somefile`, in your `AC_CONFIG_FILES` macro, your `configure` script looks for a file called `somefile.in`, and replaces the names of any output variables between @-signs with their values, calling the result `somefile`.

So, to access these definitions in a Python file `somescript.py`, put something like this in your `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT(MILHOUSE, 0.3.6)
...blah blah...
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
  some/Makefile
  some/other/Makefile
  somescript.py
])
```

Then name your Python file `somescript.py.in` and access the PACKAGE_VERSION output variable like this:

```
version = '''@PACKAGE_VERSION@'''
```

The triple quotes are probably wise, because you never know when an output variable might contain a quote.

Comment: perfect! great answer, exactly what I was looking for and applicable in other contexts (i.e. non-python) as well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The examples page of the [pyparsing wiki](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) includes [this example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/macroExpander.py) of a macro expander.  Here is the sample code that it processes:

```
#def A 100
#def ALEN A+1

char Astring[ALEN];
char AA[A];
typedef char[ALEN] Acharbuf;
```

So it will also handle macros that are defined in terms of other macros.  Should not be difficult to change '#def' to '#define'.

Comment: that would work, but i'm looking for a more generic solution to access configure-time symbols from python, rather than explicitly reading the config.h file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2211433/447356): if you are interested in a custom defined variable, be sure to use `AC_SUBST` in addition to `AC_DEFINE[_UNQUOTED]` else nothing is replaced in your config files. Using the hints from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735145/987623), I added this to my `configure.ac`

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_DEFINE_SUBST], [
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([$1], [$2], [$3])
AC_SUBST([$1], [$2])
])
...
AX_DEFINE_SUBST([OUTPUT_DIRECTORY], "$with_output", [output directory])
```

so in `config.h` I get

```
/* output directory */
#define OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/some/directory/"
```

and `config.py.in` is converted from

```
output_directory = '''@OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@'''
```

to `config.py`

```
output_directory = '''/some/directory/'''
```