# How do I combine AC_SUBST and AC_DEFINE?

Tags: autoconf

I've a `configure.ac` file containing lines like:

```
AC_DEFINE(CONF_XDISP, ":8", "X screen number")
```

These constants are used in the C source for setting compile defaults. I also have a configuration file `conf/bumblebee.conf` in which these defaults need to be set. I'm told that `AC_SUBST` can be used to get `@CONF_XDISP@` substituted for `":8"` such that the below line:

```
VGL_DISPLAY=@CONF_XDISP@
```

becomes:

```
VGL_DISPLAY=":8"
```

Making an `AC_SUBST` line for each `AC_DEFINE` does not look the best way to me as it includes a lot duplication of lines. How can I combine these options, such that I can use something like `AC_DEFINE_SUBST`? Other ideas and suggestions to improve this are welcome too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [thinton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732543/427545), I could cook up the below code:

```
# AC_DEFINE_SUBST(NAME, VALUE, DESCRIPTION)
# -----------------------------------------
AC_DEFUN([AC_DEFINE_SUBST], [
AC_DEFINE([$1], [$2], [$3])
AC_SUBST([$1], ['$2'])
])
```

For `AC_DEFINE_SUBST(CONF_XDISP, ":8", "X screen number")`, this generates a `configure` file containing:

```
$as_echo "#define CONF_XDISP \":8 \$PWD\"" >>confdefs.h

CONF_XDISP='":8"'
```

Related docs:

- http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html
- http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Macro-Definitions.html

Comment: Note that if you add indentation befor `AC_SUBST`, it'll show up in the generated `configure` code. I don't know if there is a shell that cannot handle that, but safety I'll just leave the indentation away.

Comment: The `AC_` namespace belongs to autoconf, so I suggest you use `AX_DEFINE_SUBST`.

Answer (score 7):

`m4` is a macro language, after all, so something like

```
 AC_DEFUN([AC_DEFINE_SUBST], 
   [AC_DEFINE($1,$2,$3) 
    AC_SUBST($1)])
```

should do the trick. You might have to fiddle with `[` a little to get escaping right.

Comment: Looks promising, I'm going to try it. Reference to docs: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Macro-Definitions.html#index-AC_005fDEFUN-1585

Comment: I needed to add another param to `AC_SUBST`, otherwise the keyword was replaced by an empty string. The single quotes are necessary to prevent shell interpretation. +1 for getting me in the right direction.